# Are there other ways than the AlarmManager to trigger code under specific circumstances in the Android Framework?

Tags: java, android, security, triggers, frameworks

Hello Stack Overflow community,

You might know that the Android Framework allows developers to trigger a piece of code that can be postponed using the AlarmManager and specific methods such as `setExact` :

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager am = ((AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
    int delay = //do some calculation
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + delay, pi);
}
```

Basically, this code allows triggering some other piece of code (i.e., in this TargetActivity class) under specific circumstances defined by the calculation of the `delay` variable.
You might have noticed that though some code can be triggered under specific circumstances, there are no `if` statements in this code, nor `switch/case`, nor `loops` that would emulate conditions.

Hence my question, do the community know other ways to trigger some piece of code under specific circumstances, but without `if` statements?
For instance, it could be triggering code if the phone is in a particular location, if a specific network frame is received, if a specific sms is received, if a call from a specific person is received, if the Android version is a specific version, if the phone is not an emulator, etc. All **without** `if/loop/switch/case` statements

I thank you in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: Take a look at `WorkManager`.

Comment: I will take a look, well appreciated, thank you!